How does innovation deal with the problem of different connections in NEAT?
How does innovation deal with the problem of different connections in NEAT?
An example makes it clearer: the neural network has two outputs 3 and 4, they are connected according to the scheme 10 -> 6 -> 3, 11 -> 7 -> 4, there is another neural network which has 10 -> 6 -> 4, 11 -> 7 -> 3. It turns out that here 10 -> 6 is responsible for different outputs, how does innovation in NEAT cope with this?
